# Google Maps City Crawler

Tags: routing

This question is just theoretical but it occurs to me that it can't be all that impossible.

Seeing as how Google is just a big web spider that essentially starts out at one page, like index everything starting at such and such a page dealing with basketball, how difficult/impossible would it be to give a starting point (GPS) from a city and have it find all the roads/intersections in a 10-mile radius for example? Basically 'crawl' and keep track or road names, gps points, and intersections wherever it takes a fork.

The Google Maps API would probably come into big use there, the only speedbump might be the web requests max. I could use OpenStreetMap but I'm not sure it would be able to provide as much accessibility. I'd like to write as little XML parsing as possible.

Answer (score 6):

(This is not exactly the solution you require - but close.)

**Google Maps API (v2) Driving Radius**

This takes a starting location (city centre of Memphis)
and radiates out (like a spider) to 10 miles (default)

[image]

http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html#

**FULL CREDIT** goes to Marcelo Montagna

Comment: Link is dead - is there an updated URL that you're aware of?

Comment: Looks like the domain is not renewed - https://web.archive.org/web/20110401000000*/http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html