# Traverse all roads in a city or bounded region

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, google-maps-api

Is it possible to provide a starting point(lat/long) to a drone and then simulate it to traverse through all the roads in a bounded region.

What I currently have(using OpenStreetMaps) is a list of all intersection points of all the roads in a bounded region(eg: a small sector in a city),

What I want is to make my drone to move through all the roads in that sector automatically(no manual controls) using the lat-long coordinates starting from a particular location, taking minimum possible time.

I have around 5,000 lat-long coordinates(intersection points of roads) in that sector.

Google Direction API provides the use of way-points but only 23 points can be inserted at a time. Besides, Google Maps API require 2 lat-long coordinates(start-point and end-point), what I want is to provide only a starting location and make the drone move along the roads based on some Algo in the backend that covers all roads.

Found a related question here [Google Maps City Crawler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/google-maps-city-crawler) but the link in solution does not work.

Comment: Also posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067375/traverse-all-roads-in-a-city-or-bounded-region

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem